# Lotus Notes - mailto command : select inbox

Tags: email, lotus-notes

I would like to use the mailto command in order to open Lotus Notes. I open it with success filling the to/cc/subject/body fields but I would like to choose which inbox use in order to send the mail. We have two mail inbox: the personal mail inbox and the office mail inbox shared with our department.

```
<a href="mailto:amy@company.com?cc=joe@company.com?bcc=jill@company.com?subject=The subject?body=The contents of email">Send!</a>
```

Comment: sorry: this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to select the inbox. The mailto link is a function that just opens a mail in the mailfile that is configured in the location document.

You could create two locations (one for each mailfile) and switch location before clicking the mailto- link, but that is usually not feasible.

So: Sorry, there is no solution for your request.